# How to do Monorepo setup with react and react native apps for sharing code between them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, monorepo

I want to share most of react-native login with react web. I am using react-native-web package for this. importing file in from shared folder doesn't resolve to correct path.

```
My project setup looks like this:


-MyApp

--mobile
--web
--shared
```